# Ubuntu stuck on acer logo

Tags: boot, grub2, acer

1. I was working on my computer
2. While I was working I went offline
3. I locked my computer (super + l)
4. when I tried to sign back in the password area was greyed out and it said "failed to start authorization manager" or something similar
5. I tried restarting my system but there was no option; the closest was suspend so i held power key until it restarted
6. when I went to select ubuntu in grub it would show the acer logo but the ubuntu logo didnt come and it just stayed like that forever unless i restarted; which i did
7. so i tried going into advanced options for ubuntu> recovery mode> dpkg - repair broken packages
8. this didnt change anything except now instead of saying ubuntu in grub it says debian/gnu linux

there is no error message it just stuck on boot
i guess if it were other computers it might show their respective logos

Comment: When the Acer logo shows, try pressing `ESC`. Then you can see systemd logs. See are there any strange logs.